# How do we know that the sine function can be represented as a solution to a Taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometry

I understand how sine is defined using triangles and/or the unit circle.

Sine is also defined by a power series that is found using a Taylor series and solving f(x)=c<sub>0</sub>+c<sub>1</sub>x+c<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup>+... for the coefficients.

But how do we know that sine can be accurately represented by this formula? This what I don't understand. (I believe it, I just don't understand it.)

I understand how to solve the Taylor series for sine. I know how to use a point "a" and use "x-a" instead of "a". In other words, I don't need help with the math commonly used in this.

I'm just trying to figure out how we know that sine can be represented by a power series. The step from triangles to sine is easy. The step from sine to a power series is not so obvious to me.

Comment: Please have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x09IsbVZeXo

Answer (score 1):

Going all the way from triangles to the Taylor series is, in fact, not easy, since it involves several nontrivial steps. First, we have to extend the triangle definition to the definition via the unit circle. I am going to assume that you are familiar with the unit circle definition of the sine and how it relates to the triangle definition. Then we need to show that the sine is differentiable with its second derivative equal to the negative sine. And that we can use to derive the Taylor series. Then as a last step, it needs to be shown that this function is analytic, meaning that its Taylor series converges to the function.

I am going to give you the cliff notes:

**First step, differentiability.** By definition, $\sin'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$. Calculating this limit involves using the angle addition formula and the fact that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$. A thorough derivation of both as well as the resulting derivative of the sine can be found via a quick Google search. It results in the famous fact that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$. Applying very similar techniques we can also get $\sin''(x)=\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)$. That is, $\sin$ is at least twice differentiable and satisfies $\sin''=-\sin$.

**Second step, Taylor series**. Since the Taylor coefficients are calculated using the derivatives, and knowing that $\sin(0)=0,\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$, as well as the differential equation satisfied by $\sin$, we can use induction to find them all. Specifically, since $\sin''=-\sin$, we can show inductively that the sine is infinitely differentiable and that $\sin^{(2n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and that $\sin^{(2n+1)}(0)=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Now we just have to assemble everything into the Taylor series formula.

**Third step, analyticity**. Here we can again use the fact that the sine satisfies the differential equation from before. It is a fact from the theory of differential equations that the solution to a linear ODE with analytic coefficients is also analytic. Since our ODE has coefficients 1 and -1, which are constants and thus analytic, the sine is also analytic.

All in all, the whole thing requires understanding of geometry (for the angle addition formula und the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$), calculus (to find the Taylor coefficients) and the theory of ODEs (to prove that the Taylor series converges to the sine). Detailed accounts of each step might warrant questions of their own.

Comment: @MartinR Right, I had read the question as "why is this the Taylor series?" instead of "why does this series agree with the sine?". I added a third paragraph.

Comment: Even without the theory of differential equations and analytic functions it is relatively easy to calculate that the remainder in Taylor's theorem converges to zero for all $x$, so that the Taylor series is equal to the function.

Comment: True, I hadn't thought of that.